# Typescript function generic deep inherit

Tags: typescript

I have created a hook in React and I am trying to get fully typed with Generics.
But i only get 1 drill of types.

because of the 1 drill types i get the keys correct but not the enums and such...

this:

```js
const [{ view }, setQueryStates] = useQueryStates({
        view: {
            defaultValue: 'gantt',
            enum: ['gantt', 'kanban'],
        },
    });
```

typed as:

```js
export default function useQueryStates<{
    view: {
        defaultValue: string;
        enum: string[];
    };
}>(     queries: {view: {defaultValue: string, enum: string[]}}): QueryStateResponse<{view: {defaultValue: string, enum: string[]}}>
```

insted of this:

```js
export default function useQueryStates<{
    view: {
        defaultValue: 'gantt';
        enum: ['gantt', 'kanban'];
    };
}>(     queries: {view: {defaultValue: "gantt", enum: ["gantt", "kanban"]}}): QueryStateResponse<{view: {defaultValue: "gantt", enum: ["gantt", "kanban"]}}>
```

The Generic is not drilling down...

Thhese are the types:

```js
type QueryDefinition =
    | string
    | {
            value?: string;
            defaultValue?: string;
            enum?: string[];
      };

type QueryStateParams = {
    [key: string]: QueryDefinition;
};

type ExtractQueryValue<T extends QueryDefinition> = T extends string
    ? string
    : T extends { value?: infer V; defaultValue?: infer D; enum?: (infer E)[] }
    ? E extends string
        ? (V extends string ? V : never) | (D extends string ? D : never) | (E extends string ? E : never) | ''
        : never
    : string;

type QueryState<Params extends QueryStateParams> = {
    [P in keyof Params]: ExtractQueryValue<Params[P]>;
};

type SetQueryState<Params extends QueryStateParams> = (updatedState: Partial<QueryState<Params>>) => void;

type QueryStateResponse<Params extends QueryStateParams> = [QueryState<Params>, SetQueryState<Params>];

function useQueryStates<QueryParams extends QueryStateParams>(queries: QueryParams): QueryStateResponse<QueryParams>
```

Can you help me fix the Generics of the function?

Comment: ① The word "drill" doesn't make much sense to me in this context; could you [edit] to rephrase? ② Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NrQrVw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I want the type to consider everything, currently its considering only the keys...
For example it will type the state's optional keys as far as i inserted them, but ignores the enum (it says string[] instead the enum that i wrote)

Comment:  It doesn't look like you responded to either of my comments. I will try again. ① The word "[drill](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/drill)" is confusing; please [edit] to replace the term with something more conventional.  ② If I understand what you want correctly, then my suggested solution is [shown here in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NrQrVw) <-- that's a link to an IDE, please click it.  Does that fix your issue?  If so I'll write up an answer. If not, what am I issing?